# How to concatenate all values of array in Xcode

Tags: iphone, nsarray

I am new in iOS and i am not able to find solution of my question . So please tell me how can i concatenate all values of array in iOS

Comment: I think you search like this solution. But before posting any question you have to search properly on google. Here is your solution given by me: [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14438617/1450762)

Comment: If you found the solution of your Problem then You should "Mark answer Accepted".

Answer (score 2):

**Answer : [-componentsJoinedByString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString:)** .

It will join the components in the array by the specified string and return a string representation of the array.

**Use :**    `NSString *finalStr = [yourArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];`

GoodLuck !!!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using string values in NSArray then it is quite simple.
You can just run for loop and use a NSMutableString to append the data.

```
NSArray *_array;//Your Initialized Array

  NSMutableString *_string  =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    for(int i= 0 ;i<[_array count];i++)
    {
        [_string appendFormat:@"%@",[_array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    NSLog(@"_string = %@",_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSMutableString* theString = [NSMutableString string];
   for (int i=0; i<[array count];i++){
       [theString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i ",i]];
   }
   NSLog(@"mystirng=%@", theString;);
```